# How do I count the number of items an Integer occur in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

My idea is to build a list having the user writing in 5 different ints (doesnt have to be even numbers) and then write a number to see how many time that number occurs in the list. How do I do this? This is my example code im having problems with:

```
package Listor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> evenNumbersList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("Write 5 even numbers: ");
        int evenNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            evenNumber = s.nextInt();
            evenNumbersList.add(evenNumber);

        }
        System.out.println(evenNumbersList);
        System.out.println("Write a number and see how many times it occurs: ");
        int intHappens = s.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < evenNumbersList.size(); i++) {
            if (i == intHappens) {
                sum += 1;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(sum);

    }

}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you tell us specifically what's wrong with this code, instead of saying you're "having problems with" it.  What output do you get and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors I see:

1) Your `for` loop needs to start from 0, not 1.

2) Your `if` statement should be `if (evenNumbersList.get(i) == intHappens)`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to iterate over the **evenNumberList** list and compare the values in the list with **intHappens**. Use a **for(Variabletype varname : List list)** for-loop. Read up on **Enhanced For-Loops**